# Spring Hibernate when update an user it deletes its role

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've a problem with spring hibernate, when I update an user this deletes the associated role...
Could it be a cascade matters? I've tried with every kind of cascade config...

**Person**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }  )
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",  
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},  
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}  
    )
.
.
.
}
```

**Role**

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="roles")  
public class Role {  

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue  
    private Integer id;  

    private String authority;  

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ) 
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",   
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")},  
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}  
    )
    private Set<User> userRoles;
.
.
.
}
```

**UserRole**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private int roleId;
.
.
.
}
```

**UserDaoImpl**

```
@Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        try {
            this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(user);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

I get the user (the one who has logged in) like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editUser(ModelMap map,Principal principal) {
        try{
            //Get logged in username
            String loggedUserEmail = principal.getName();
            User user = userService.getUserByEmail(loggedUserEmail);

            map.addAttribute("user", user);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("/user/edit/---"+e);
        }


        return "forms/userForm";
    }
```

And then I try to update after committing some changes on the user form.
Ah, and I insert the UserRole like this:

```
//Add userRole to db
            UserRole userRole = new UserRole();
            userRole.setUserId(user.getId());
            userRole.setRoleId(1);
            userRoleService.addUserRole(userRole);
```

Comment: You dont have to mention cascade on the collection in the user class, if you dont mention the cascade there, you have to manually add the user roles using a different Dao implementation updateRoles(set<Role> roles) .

Answer (score 0):

`Session.update` makes a detached object persistent (meaning the Hibernate session's version of the object now reflects those changes). So if you pass in an object that you didn't get from the current Hibernate session (maybe something hanging out in the Http session or something you just created with `new`), then that object may not have a link to its UserRole, and when you call `update` Hibernate thinks that because that reference is missing that means you are telling it to delete the UserRole.

Guessing you're using an existing User that has an Id but is detached from the session: try using the id from that user to call Session.load to get a new attached user (so it will be up-to-date, including having the existing UserRole), then make the desired changes to that object, then let that be committed. The UserRole should be retained.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer; I've edited my question inserting the details about how I get and update the user... is that the correct way? Unfortunately It still deletes its associated role... I've to say that if I try to get the user role before to update it it correctly retrieves it!

Comment: @Andrea: so you do have a detached User. did you confirm if the UserRole is on the detached User? because i've had to deal with schemes before where entities get repopulated from forms and it's easy to lose stuff like this.

Comment: If you mean if I can get the role of the user before to update it the answer is yes! By the way I've updated the question adding the way I save the user role everytime a new user is created

Comment: @Andrea: did you try the experiment in my second paragraph?

Comment: Can you make me an exemple please?

Comment: I've tried this: session.contains(user) and it returns false!